# I am trying to display the detail icon at far right by using webkit-details-marker but not getting the desired output

Tags: html, css

```css
::-webkit-details-marker {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="ques-block">
  <details>
    <summary class="question">How important is accordian?</summary>
    <p class="answer">
      Accordian is type of question and answer forum in which qestion is in the question block and answer is in the answer block.
    </p>
</div>
```

In the CSS section the `::-webkit-details-marker{}` is not working, and even if it is working the output is not visible; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt you can style it like this. You'll need to remove the marker and add a customized marker yourself.

Comment: It seems that Google have deprecated the `::-webkit-details-marker` selector: "*...[we] also support `::marker` pseudo element selector for `<summary>`, and remove `::-webkit-details-marker` pseudo element selector.*" (ref: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss/c/uXcmWMm2gRQ?pli=1). Can I Use also confirms: [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_-webkit-details-marker).

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate it using `direction`

```css
.question {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}

.question>div {
  display: inline-block;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="ques-block">
  <details>
    <summary class="question">
      <div>How important is accordian?</div>
    </summary>
    <p class="answer">
      Accordian is type of question and answer forum in which qestion is in the question block and answer is in the answer block.
    </p>
  </details>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to override marker style, but I can suggest a workaround.

```css
details summary {
  position: relative;
}

details summary::after {
  content: "▶";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

details[open] summary::after {
  content: "▼";
}

summary {
  list-style: none
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ques-block">
  <details>
    <summary class="question">How important is accordian?</summary>
    <p class="answer">
      Accordian is type of question and answer forum in which qestion is in the question block and answer is in the answer block.
    </p>
  </details>
</div>
```